# How to remove unwanted ad sense ads from Home Page?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, ads, adsense

Some of my viewers are reporting seeing (unwanted) ads from ad sense on the top of my Home Page at wwww.shifter.pt

I've already changed the FTP access password, DB password and the passwords from all users of the website. Restarted the server and nothing changed.

The code from the ads looks like this and it's located before the header:

```
<center><script async="" src="//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script><script async="" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.gstatic.com/pub-config/ca-pub-7837806915816060.js"></script><script async="" src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- de -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px" data-ad-client="ca-pub-7837806915816060" data-ad-slot="1724932034" data-adsbygoogle-status="done"><ins id="aswift_0_expand" style="display:inline-table;border:none;height:90px;margin:0;padding:0;position:relative;visibility:visible;width:728px;background-color:transparent"><ins id="aswift_0_anchor" style="display:block;border:none;height:90px;margin:0;padding:0;position:relative;visibility:visible;width:728px;background-color:transparent"><iframe width="728" height="90" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="true" onload="var i=this.id,s=window.google_iframe_oncopy,H=s&amp;&amp;s.handlers,h=H&amp;&amp;H[i],w=this.contentWindow,d;try{d=w.document}catch(e){}if(h&amp;&amp;d&amp;&amp;(!d.body||!d.body.firstChild)){if(h.call){setTimeout(h,0)}else if(h.match){try{h=s.upd(h,i)}catch(e){}w.location.replace(h)}}" id="aswift_0" name="aswift_0" style="left:0;position:absolute;top:0;"></iframe></ins></ins></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
<br>
<script async="" src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- uk -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:inline-block;width:336px;height:280px" data-ad-client="ca-pub-7837806915816060" data-ad-slot="8650939636" data-adsbygoogle-status="done"><ins id="aswift_1_expand" style="display:inline-table;border:none;height:280px;margin:0;padding:0;position:relative;visibility:visible;width:336px;background-color:transparent"><ins id="aswift_1_anchor" style="display:block;border:none;height:280px;margin:0;padding:0;position:relative;visibility:visible;width:336px;background-color:transparent"><iframe width="336" height="280" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="true" onload="var i=this.id,s=window.google_iframe_oncopy,H=s&amp;&amp;s.handlers,h=H&amp;&amp;H[i],w=this.contentWindow,d;try{d=w.document}catch(e){}if(h&amp;&amp;d&amp;&amp;(!d.body||!d.body.firstChild)){if(h.call){setTimeout(h,0)}else if(h.match){try{h=s.upd(h,i)}catch(e){}w.location.replace(h)}}" id="aswift_1" name="aswift_1" style="left:0;position:absolute;top:0;"></iframe></ins></ins></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script> 
<br>
<script async="" src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- US -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:inline-block;width:320px;height:100px" data-ad-client="ca-pub-7837806915816060" data-ad-slot="1127672839" data-adsbygoogle-status="done"><ins id="aswift_2_expand" style="display:inline-table;border:none;height:100px;margin:0;padding:0;position:relative;visibility:visible;width:320px;background-color:transparent"><ins id="aswift_2_anchor" style="display:block;border:none;height:100px;margin:0;padding:0;position:relative;visibility:visible;width:320px;background-color:transparent"><iframe width="320" height="100" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="true" onload="var i=this.id,s=window.google_iframe_oncopy,H=s&amp;&amp;s.handlers,h=H&amp;&amp;H[i],w=this.contentWindow,d;try{d=w.document}catch(e){}if(h&amp;&amp;d&amp;&amp;(!d.body||!d.body.firstChild)){if(h.call){setTimeout(h,0)}else if(h.match){try{h=s.upd(h,i)}catch(e){}w.location.replace(h)}}" id="aswift_2" name="aswift_2" style="left:0;position:absolute;top:0;"></iframe></ins></ins></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script> </center>
```

Thank you for your time!

EDIT

I've been able to block the code from showing on desktop version of the website but the problem remains when you access the website on the Facebook in-app browser for example.

Comment: and you did not include any of this code in your page?

Comment: I'm confused. Are you saying you have adsense ads on your page that you didn't place there?

Comment: @DavidP.Caldwell no, we have ad sense on different banners in other locations of the website but not at the top.

Comment: Can you give us some more details? Your problem is too broad to do anything about it except guessing in the dark.

Comment: @LajosArpad please help me understand in which way I could be more specific?

Comment: For instance a link to the page where the problem occurs.

Comment: @LajosArpad you can try to see it in http://shifter.pt/2014/12/branding-anonymous-a-construcao-da-marca-anti-marcas/

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.adsbygoogle').css('display','none');
});
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/4fvw0mky/)
But that isn't really a good fix, you should probably contact Google and see if they can fix it.

Comment: where should i paste that?

Comment: Your solution solved the problem on Desktop version of the website but if the website is accessed from the Facebook in-app browser it still show the ads

Comment: View it in mobile, and get the class used there. Google probably uses a different class for mobile ads

Answer (score 0):

This is my 99.9% guess based on your report: your problem is your hosting provider, who are attempting to make money off their hosted sites by inserting ads at the top of pages.

While there are potentially some awkward hacks you could use to take them out (my guess is you can somehow use JavaScript to go through the DOM and delete the DOM nodes, assuming you even have that much control over the content), my answer, for Stack Overflow purposes, is: find a different hosting provider. You may have even signed an agreement allowing them to add the ads in this way, in which case taking them out might violate their hosting terms. In any case, allowing the hosting provider to insert ads at the top of pages is -- I am hoping -- a very uncommon way to do this, so it should be easy to find a mechanism where that won't happen.

The discussion about who to use as a host, or how to find one, is unfortunately outside the scope of Stack Overflow.

Comment: I really doubt that as the server providers are a friends of mine :)

Comment: I stand by my theory until you come up with another explanation. Code doesn't just end up in pages.